# shift task from one thread pool to another thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a List of thread pools executor each size 50, I want like when some executor does not have any pending jobs in their queue or running less task then pool size then they can able to take a job from another executor queue who has more task and execute.

So I created another thread that runs the below method in some time interval and shift jobs but it is not working well.
problems

1. more task added than their pool size even I given condition in while less-equal than pool size but I don't know why more task transferred.
2. suppose pool1 has less task so task added from others in pool1 then somehow again pool1 to back into some other pool in another loop iteration, not working well it's happening with many pools.

Is there any other way to do it. I don't think the way I am doing it good approach and it's not working well.

Please suggest a way do it.

```
public void shiftTaskInIdleThreadPool() {
    for(ThreadPoolExecutor executor : threadPoolExecutorsList){
        if(executor.getCorePoolSize() > executor.getActiveCount()){
            for (ThreadPoolExecutor executor1 : threadPoolExecutorList){
                while(executor1.getQueue().size() > 0 && executor.getActiveCount() < executor.getCorePoolSize()){
                    executor.execute(executor1.getQueue().remove());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do but what I can't understand the reason behind it. Can you explain why a list of say n thread pools of size 50 rather than one thread pool of size 50n?